# Strange close lid behavior on GNOME

Tags: gnome, suspend, power-management, lid, gnome-power-manager

Recently I decided to switch to GNOME and it was glorious until I found out that I can't close the lid without the GNOME killing itself. I tried everything from the `dconf-editor` method to killing `gnome-power-manager` and replace it with `xfce4-power-manager`. Here's a video that should describe it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxddQ5-JNMA

Also, I tried this with both `gdm` and `lightdm`

Update: it's really funny how everything works well on the LiveUSB but breaks after I install it.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Ubuntu GNOME Zesty Zapus 17.04 with `nvidia-375`